# Angular date pipe is adding one more year with transform in Firefox

Tags: angular, date, firefox

I have a date that comes like this 1-Nov-2018. When I change to a date type object using new Date() and transform it using `new DatePipe('en-US').transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')`
it adds one more year to the date. The issue happens with Firefox, with Chrome works as expected

Comment: Seems to be something else going on because it comes out as `'2018-11-01'` using the settings you provided. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-enbbhc?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I got '2019-11-01' with your stackblitz on Firefox [imgur](https://imgur.com/PXQlgNp)